# Changing the opacity on a canvas toggled with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, hover

I've been trying to create a replica of a menu inside a game, but there's one thing missing. When you hover the different canvas pieces I want them to change opacity, but since it's not a div or an image it's quite complicated. And since I'm still trying to learn all this I'm wondering how I would go by to make this possible.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkx8dzn0/2/

My Javascript:

```
var can=document.getElementById("NewCanvas");
    var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(48,152);
    ctx.lineTo(42,9);
    ctx.lineTo(305,10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(560,152);
    ctx.lineTo(540,10);
    ctx.lineTo(305,9);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(561,150);
    ctx.lineTo(613,206);
    ctx.lineTo(613,375);
    ctx.lineTo(606,480);
    ctx.lineTo(536,442);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();


    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(563,455);
    ctx.lineTo(564,603);
    ctx.lineTo(305,602);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(305,602);
    ctx.lineTo(48,602);
    ctx.lineTo(45,447);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.moveTo(305,306);
    ctx.lineTo(45,447);
    ctx.lineTo(1,447);
    ctx.lineTo(1,152);
    ctx.lineTo(48,152);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
    }

  img.src='http://i.imgur.com/povcJq8.png';
```

And the HMTL/CSS:

```
<canvas style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -300px; margin-top: -300px;"id="NewCanvas" height="700" width="700">
</canvas>
```

Comment: So my quess it that you want 1 'pie piece' to be lit up when hovered over it?

Comment: @dwana Yeah, exactly!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need to do is keep track of where the mouse is on the screen.  I updated your fiddle with something that works to show you where you are pointing.  Once you know which section you are pointing to, you can use the same canvas methods that you apparently know how to do to create the overlays.

http://jsfiddle.net/wkx8dzn0/5/

You can see I added two functions to the bottom of your JS.  `getMousePos` returns the position in X and Y coordinates of the mouse on the canvas.  The other function runs whenever you move the mouse on the canvas, use the `addEventListener` method.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var centerX = 305;
var centerY = 306;
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left - centerX,
    y: - ( evt.clientY - rect.top - centerY )
  };
}

can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
var mousePos = getMousePos(can, evt);
var angle = Math.atan(mousePos.y/mousePos.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
if (mousePos.x < 0){
  angle = 180 + angle;
}else if (mousePos.y < 0){
  angle = 360 + angle;
}

  var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y + ' atan ' + angle;
// now you know where the mouse is, create your overlay depending on where the mouse is
if (angle <= 30){
  message += " SMGs";
}else if (angle <= 90){
  message += " HEAVY";
}else if (angle <= 150){
  message += " PISTOLS";
}else if (angle <= 210){
  message += " GRENADES";
}else if (angle <= 270){
  message += " GEAR";
}else if (angle <= 330){
  message += " RIFLES";
}else{
  message += " SMGs";
}

$('#msg').text(message);

}, false);
```

Comment: Oh my, that's insanly great! Thank you so much Jeffery, you really helped me out a lot!